# Android Immediately Destroy Activities (Debug-Flag), Realistic?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

On my Android Emulator I have the Flag "Immediately Destroy Activities".
Under this condition my App does not do what I want it to do, because my MainActivity always has to be on the ActivityStack.
Is it a real scenario that Activitys of the ActivityStack are destroyed, while my app is running?

Comment: I've re-spelled your whole title based on http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a real scenario that Activitys of the ActivityStack are destroyed, while my app is running?

It is certainly possible for an activity to be destroyed at any time, so long as that activity is not on the screen.

Comment: Ok, that should be no problem, cause my app is that restarted (if needed) with my startactivity i think. But is there a chance to get destroyed for invisible activitys to get destroyed at runtime?

Comment: @Till: I have no idea what an "invisible activity" is.

Comment: Sorry, invisible activity is an activity that has started another activity by `startActvitiy(..)`.

Comment: @Till: Then, absolutely, "invisible activities" are destroyed by Android.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. But they are not destroyed every time. Right? Is there a nice way handling it? I use `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` and want my mainactivity to be started first at every time. So if my mainactivity is killed from the stack it will not be Launched.